# Any steps before install meteor-postgres? I can not connect the database

Tags: javascript, postgresql, meteor

I put the issue for meteor-postgres 
Is there any step should taken before install meteor？
since my meteor-postgres is still do not connnected.

I write the issue on github:

https://github.com/storeness/meteor-postgres/issues/7

Any other tools can connect postgresql database for meteor framework

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about meteor-postgres but the connect string

> postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/meteorpg

translates to: There is a Postgresql server running on localhost port 5432 with an existing database with the name meteorpg, which the user postgres identified with the password postgres has access to.

> ECONNREFUSED

indicates, that there is nothing accepting TCP connections in this place.

So do you have an Postgresql daemon running at all?